# How to make a beep noise in my batch game

Tags: batch-file

I am making a batch game and I was wondering how I can make a beep noise when I press a key.

For example:
1) Mage
2) Warrior

If I want to be a `Mage` and I press `1` and then enter I want it to make a beep noise.
How do I do this?

Comment: Look on what Stack Overflow search results on searching for [\[batch-file\] beep](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bbatch-file%5D+beep). You are not the first one who wrote a batch file "game" and wants a beep noise to output on execution of the batch file.

Comment: Sort of. I just want it to beep when I make a selection. Not necessarily a beep but just a sound when enter is pressed. Like the old NES games. This is what I'm going for.

Answer (score 0):

Windows has a `Beep` API function that you can call, as per [this link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms679277(v=vs.85).aspx).

I would simply develop a very small executable that took the two arguments (frequency and duration) on the command line and used those to call this function.

Here's the starting point for such a beast, a console application in Visual Studio:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <Windows.h>

int errorExit(char *str) {
    std::cerr << str << std::endl;
    return 1;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    if (argc != 3)
        return errorExit("beep: needs frequency and millisecs");

    int freq = std::atoi(argv[1]);
    if ((freq < 37) || (freq > 32767))
         return errorExit("beep: frequency must be 37..32767");

    int duration = std::atoi(argv[2]);
    if ((duration < 1) || (duration > 10000))
        return errorExit("beep: duration must be 1..10000");

    Beep(freq, duration);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Would this work in notepad? If so would this code make it so that when I press enter it beeps?

Comment: @Alex, if you mean "can you create the file in Notepad?", sure, but you'll need a compiler to turn it into an executable. MS provides VS2015Community for free under non-big-company circumstances. Having it beep when you press ENTER depends on how you code your cmd file, this code is simply a way to get a beep out of Windows.

Comment: Where in my code would I place your code for it to beep when I press enter? What I mean by that is what code should be followed by your code in order for this to work?         Sorry if you are confused of my questions I am new at coding.

Comment: @Alex, that depends entirely on *where* in your batch game you want the sound to play. Your question stated that you were making such a batch game and you needed to know how to get it to play a sound. This solution will allow you to do so if you just place something like `beep.exe 700 250` in your batch file. I assumed from your question that you had the rest of the batch game in hand. If not, you probably will need to ask a few more questions :-)

Comment: Thank you so much for your help!